# Function to Search for a Specified Value Within an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am fairly new to JavaScript and StackOverflow and am currently trying to create a function to search for a specialized value within a created array. I have written out what seems like a function that would work, any ideas or any obvious flaws in it? It is currently not working. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<td>Index: <input style = "width: 50px" input type ="textbox" id="Index"  value="2"/></td> <!-- HTML code to create the index textbox -->
<br/> <!-- Line Break -->
Value: <input style = "width: 50px" input type = "textbox" id="Value" value = "10"/> <!-- HTML code to create the value textbox -->
<br />
<td>Enter Value to Find: <input style="width: 50px;" type="textbox" value="20" />
<input type="button" value="Search Array" onClick = searchArray(); /></td>
<br />
<input type = "button" value = "Create" onClick = "createArray();"/>
<input type="button" value="Insert into Array" onClick="insertIntoArray();" />
<div id="result">
```

JS:

```
var myArray = [];
var d = ""; //This global variable is going to be used for clearing and populating the screen 

function createArray (){
    //This functions is to clear the current information on the screen so the array can populate
  clearScreen(); 
  //The next thing we want to do according to the lecture is create a FOR loop to run 100 times to set the various array values
  for (var i = 0; i <100; i++){
  myArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()* 100 + 1); //Math.floor rounds an number downards to the nearest integer then returns. Math.random returns a        integer randomly withing given variables
  }
  popScreen(); //function to fill the screen with the array 
}


function clearScreen(){
d = ""; //Global string variable mentioned before 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
}


function popScreen(){
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++){
    d += i + ' : ' + myArray[i] + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = d;
}


function insertIntoArray(){
    clearScreen();
    var i= parseInt(document.getElementById("Index").value);
        var j = parseInt(document.getElementById("Value").value);
d = "inserting " + j+ " at " + i + "<br/>";
    
    var temp = myArray[i];
        for (i; i < 100; i++) {
        myArray[i] = j;
      j = temp
        temp = myArray[i+1];
      }
    popScreen();
}

**function searchArray(myArray, value){
  var searchResult = 0;
  var searchIndex = -1;
  for(var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    searchResult++;
    if(myArray[i] == value){
        searchIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (searchIndex == -1){
    console.log("Element inquiry not found in array. Total Searched: " + searchResult);
  }else{
    console.log("Element found at index: " + searchIndex + ", search count: " + searchResult);
    }**
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this yourself and not using the built-in Array methods like `filter`, `map`, `reduce` etc etc? You can see all available [here on the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: You might also look into [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which looks to be the same functionality you're trying to accomplish with `searchArray`.

Comment: @JohanJarvi - I am participating in a Data Structures course and my idea is that they want us to learn the fundamentals?

Comment: @mrrogers - Thanks! Does this function with user input so that the user can specify what they would want to find in the array?

Comment: Built in functions are "fundamentals"

Comment: @Cjmarkham - 100% agree! Not sure why there is a handicap put on it :(

Comment: Nice conversation above... But this said, what exactly is not working with your `searchArray` function? -- The HTML would be useful.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - I have added my HTML to the post. When pressing the button, I get the following error:

<a class='gotoLine' href='#99:28'>99:28</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

I am assuming this has to do with line 47 of my code:
for(var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++)

Comment: You're calling `searchArray()` with no arguments but it requires 2 (`myArray` and `value`). This means that `myArray` within the scope of your function is `undefined`

Comment: You have `onClick = searchArray();`. So you are calling the `searchArray` method without arguments. But your function is defined as `searchArray(myArray, value)` so it expects two arguments.  The first is later being used as `myArray.length` and since you did not pass it, it is `undefined` and does not have a `length` property.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - Forgive me, but I am a little confused. Should I pass these arguments when calling the function within the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the fact there are no arguments passed to the `searchArray` function via the inline `onclick` attribute... And they are necessary.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

The error thrown is because `myArray` is undefined and therefore has no `length` property.

---

To have it working, I would modify the HTML from:

```
<input type="button" value="Search Array" onClick = searchArray(); />
```

to:

```
<input type="button" value="Search Array" onClick = searchArray(this); />
```

And the function would change like this:

```
function searchArray(element) {

  let value = element.previousElementSibling.value
  // rest unchanged
```

`searchArray` being already defined at global scope, you don't need to pass it.

But you need the `value` from the input right before the button. You can get it using [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling).